# Sort Search Results based on character match percentage

Tags: swift, sorting, search, full-text-search, uisearchbar

I have a search bar and a tableView where I update the tableview rows based on the text typed in the search bar. Below is the code I am using to match the searched text with values I have in the variable `productTagsArray`. Everything is working just fine and the results are populating to my `searchResults` variable with no problem.

```
var productTagsArray : [[String : [String]]] = [[:]]
var searchResults: [[String : [String]]] = [[:]]

func filterContent(for SearchText: String){

    searchResults = productTagsArray.filter({ (productTagsArray) -> Bool in
        for product in productTagsArray {
            if let tags = product.value as? [String] {
                for tag in tags {
                    let isMatch = tag.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(SearchText)
                    return isMatch
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        return false
    })
}

func updateSearchResultsSearchBar(for searchController: UISearchBar) {
    if let searchText = searchBar.text{
        filterContent(for: searchText)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now I need to make an improvement to the results populating into the variable `searchResults`. I would like to SORT it based on the `percentage of the total characters matching`. So if the `SearchText` matches the `tag` by 80% vs. another tag is matching the `SearchText` by 50%. I want the `sorted searchResults` to store the one with higher rate before the one with the lower matching rate.

Example:

`SearchText` is `Tomato` (6 characters)

`tag1` is `Organic Tomato` (14 characters including space)

`tag2` is `Organic Small Tomato` (20 characters including space)

tag1 character matching rate is 43% (6/14 = 43%)

tag2 character matching rate is 30% (6/20 = 30%)

Now I want sort `searchResults` based on the percentage so tag1 is first and tag2 is second.

Note: There are plenty of tags

This is searchResults before sorting:

```
searchResults: [["1" : [Organic Small Tomato, Organic, Small, Tomato]], ["2" : [Organic Tomato, Organic, Tomato]]]
```

This is searchResults after sorting (the outcome I am looking for):

```
searchResults: [["2" : [Organic Tomato, Organic, Tomato]], ["1" : [Organic Small Tomato, Organic, Small, Tomato]]]
```

The logic for this sorting should be from the matching percentage with `seachText` I explain above. since Organic Tomato has 43% and its higher than 30% for Organic Small Tomato; then Organic index in searchResults should change to zero from one.

Comment: sort the results elements based on their character count

Comment: Not related to your question but you are initializing your arrays with an empty dictionary. I would also remove Array from its naming. `var productTags: [[String: [String]]] = []`

Comment: @LeoDabus can you share your code on how I could do that?

Comment: edit your question and post a result sample

Comment: btw show your actual productTagsArray declaration type. This is not your real code

Comment: why do you have an array of a single dictionary instead of just a dictionary?

Comment: I just update my question showing those two variables. Would that work? So based on the `searchText` I am filtering  `searchResult`. Which is already done in the code in the question. Then I want to sort the search result based on the first index of the value array match rate.

Comment: I might change that array of a single dictionary in the future; as I agree it doesnt need to be like that. But that cause a lot of other changes in my code so for now I am just using the same variable until I change that later

Comment: `for index in searchResults.indices {`
        `for (key,value) in searchResults[index] {`
            `searchResults[index][key] = value.sorted { $0.count<$1.count }`
        `}`
    `}`

Comment: Thanks, but this one is sorting the value. Right? but I want to sort the position of the array of the dictionary in `searchResults` so if the position of the array of a dictionary is 1 before sorting; I want to move it to zero in searchResults after sorting

Comment: edit your question and add the actual value and the expected result

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just edited the question, showing what the searchResults look like before sorting; and what it should look like after sorting based on character matching % with `searchText`. I hope this clarifies it

Comment: Perfect! thats it! many thanks. If you want to post as answer I can accept it on my end

Comment: It was actually wrong I was getting the array count but it should be the first element of the array character count

Comment: oh right! Thanks for let me know. Good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply sort your dictionary array based on the character count of the first string of your values of the first key:

```
searchResults.sort { 
    $0.first?.value.first?.count ?? 0 < $1.first?.value.first?.count ?? 0
}
```